# Laravel check pivot table to see if user is assigned to team

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

In my app users can create teams, however, if a team already exists then the user can request to join the existing team. I don't want users requesting to join a team they are already a member of so I need a controller query that will check the pivot table to see if the existing team.id is assigned to the user.id.  I then will use this data to change what info is displayed to the user, using `@if(!empty($hasTeam))` in the blade view. Selecting what info to show based on whether or not the user is assigned to the existing team.

I have tried options like the following in my controller:

```
$hasTeam = User::has('churchteams')->get();
```

or

```
$hasTeam = $user->churchteams()->where('team.id', $existing->id)->exists();
```

or

```
$hasTeam = User::where('id', $user)->whereHas('churchteams', function ($q) use ($existing) {
                $q->where('id', $existing->id);
            })
                ->exists();
```

and

```
$hasTeam = $existing->churchteams()->whereHas('team', function ($q) use ($existing) {
                $q->where('id', $existing->id);
            })
                ->exists();
```

But I haven't found anything that works.

This is my controller:

```
            $user = auth()->user();

            $existing = Team::where('ebaptist_id', $request->input('church'))->first();

            $hasTeam = (Insert pivot table query Here);

            $body = '<html><head></head><body><span><b>' . $user->name . '  (' . $user->email . ')</b> has requested to join your church as a team member, if you would like to add ' . $user->name . ' as a user with your church, ' .
                '<a href="' . route('admin.users.create') . '"> please add them in your account</a>.</span>' .
                '</body></html>';
            $existing->userjoin()->whereHas('role', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('id', 3);
            })->each(function ($admin) use ($body) {
                Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($body, $admin) {
                    $message->to($admin->email, $admin->name)
                        ->from('admin@email.org', env('APP_NAME') . ' App')
                        ->subject("Church team member joining request.")
                        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
                });
            });
            return redirect('/admin/home');
```

This is my User model

```
    public function churchteams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_user');
    }
```

How would I get this to function properly?

Comment: Why doesn't `$hasTeam = $user->churchteams()->where('team.id', $existing->id)->exists();` work?

Comment: It does not seem to return any data. When I use ```@if(!empty($hasTeam))``` in blade, it does not seem to have return a variable. $hasTeam is still empty. I can't seem to get it so $hasTeam ever has any data. I know this because when I drop the exclamation mark and just go with ```@if(empty($hasTeam))``` instead of ```@if(!empty($hasTeam))``` thus changing the if statement to adjust the view if $hasTeam is empty it always displays the view designed for empty. So this tells me that $hasTeam is being returned as empty. Thus that query is not returning any data.

Comment: You are not passing the variables to the view, how is blade supposed to know what `$hasTeam` is if you are not sending it your variables?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views